# How do I deserialise this JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I haven't done anything with JSON before... so I am probably just missing a step.

Here is an example of the JSON I want to deserialise:

```
{"item":{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4765_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4765_obj_big.gif?id=4798","id":4798,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant brutal","description":"Blunt adamantite arrow...ouch","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":237},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0},"members":"true","day30":{"trend":"positive","change":"+1.0%"},"day90":{"trend":"negative","change":"-0.0%"},"day180":{"trend":"positive","change":"+0.0%"}}}
```

I put this into "Json 2 C#" and ended up creating this new .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RSTool.Models
{

    public class Current
    {
        public string trend { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Today
    {
        public string trend { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Day30
    {
        public string trend { get; set; }
        public string change { get; set; }
    }

    public class Day90
    {
        public string trend { get; set; }
        public string change { get; set; }
    }

    public class Day180
    {
        public string trend { get; set; }
        public string change { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string icon_large { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string typeIcon { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Current current { get; set; }
        public Today today { get; set; }
        public string members { get; set; }
        public Day30 day30 { get; set; }
        public Day90 day90 { get; set; }
        public Day180 day180 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Item item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, I have the class. I can retrieve the JSON from its location as a string, but I really have no idea how to deserialise it... I have installed Newtonsoft.Json and have tried using PopulateObject and also Deserializer but not with any luck...

Assuming that my JSON is stored as a string called "json", how would I go about storing that query and then retrieving the item name, for example?

Comment: It compiles... But I have no idea then how I find that information? I tried just showing the item name in a msgbox, but nothing I put in there appears to wrok? =/

Comment: What do you mean by "find that information"? I've added how to show the name in a message box to my answer.

Comment: Just commented on answer, intellisense wasn't showing up in VS. >.< restarted and now it is. Will accept answer once it lets me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

I just tested this successfully given the code you supplied.

You can then access properties of object as normal:

```
MessageBox.Show(deserialized.item.name);
```

Comment: Oh, >.<

I had literally tried this already, but when typing into the messagebox I was putting "deserialized." and no intellisense was popping up, so I thought there was nothing available within that... Restarting VS has made the intellisense appear now... Thats annoying! Thanks for the answer. :D